# input type="checkbox" в Spring + Thymeleaf

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Как в Spring правильно принимать данные с checkbox?

Я пытался следующий вариант:

#### Controller.java:

```java
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/test")
public class TestController {

    @GetMapping
    public ModelAndView getTest(){
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        modelAndView.setViewName("test");
        boolean confirm1 = false;
        modelAndView.addObject("confirm1", confirm1);
        return modelAndView;
    }


    @PostMapping
    public ModelAndView postDeleteAccount(
            @ModelAttribute("confirm1") boolean confirm1,
            BindingResult bindingResult
    ){
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        modelAndView.setViewName("test");
        if(!confirm1){
            bindingResult
                    .rejectValue("confirm1", "error.confirm1",
                            "*You must confirm these conditions."
                    );
        }
        return modelAndView;
    }
}
```

#### Test.html:

```java
<label th:for="confirm1">Тест действия checkbox</label>
<input type="checkbox" th:field="*{confirm1}" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Ответ не идеальный, но рабочий.

#### Изменение в Thymeleaf-файле:

Итак, для начала изменим в Thymeleaf-файле строку с `input type="checkbox"`.
До:

```html
<input type="checkbox" th:field="*{confirm1}">
```

После:

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="confirm1" th:checked="*{confirm1}" />
```

#### Изменение в Controller:

`th:checked` имеет два значения: `null` и `on`, а это значит, что тип данных `Boolean` нам не подходит, а значит надо использовать `String`.

Вот как теперь выглядит `GetMapping`:

```java
    @GetMapping
    public ModelAndView getTest(){
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        modelAndView.setViewName("test");
        String confirm1 = null;
        modelAndView.addObject("confirm1", confirm1);
        return modelAndView;
    }
```

Вот как выглядит теперь `PostMapping`:

```java
@PostMapping
    public ModelAndView postDeleteAccount(
            @ModelAttribute("confirm1") String confirm1,
            BindingResult bindingResult
    ){
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        modelAndView.setViewName("test");
        if(!confirm1){
            bindingResult
                    .rejectValue("confirm1", "error.confirm1",
                            "*You must confirm these conditions."
                    );
        }
        return modelAndView;
    }
```

#### P.S.

`BindResult` вроде НЕ работает с объектом String, потому что требуется Объект с конструктором. Данный пример является абстрактным и направлен на то, чтобы показать, работу с `input type="checkbox"`